# AT theme mobile

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have made a site in Drupal with the Sky theme.  All works fine, but the main menu is not showing on mobile smartphones.  I tried AT extensions,  but this did not help.

Any ideas?  This is the site:   [lodge-ghent.com](http://www.lodge-ghent.com)

Kindly help!

Comment: As i didnt find a solution yet, i disabled the responsive setting in AT, so the site that si mentioned, wont show this problem anymore...

Answer (score 0):

It's problem in CSS, in file lodge.css  in selector #menu-bar you should delete height: 35px; 
And for better view on mobile, delete in selector #content min-height: 616px; or replace with media queries. Great coding for you!